# Disable IntelliJ debugging of JavaExec task

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea

A Gradle plugin I am using creates and binds `JavaExec` task that is a dependency of `compileJava`.

Every time I debug any Gradle task (e.g. `run`) from IntelliJ that depends on `compileJava`, IntelliJ also attaches a debugger to the JVM of the tool's `JavaExec` task. This is annoying for two reasons:

1. it wastes time because debugging is slower than running normally,
2. it wastes even more time because it never skips the `JavaExec` task despite it being `UP-TO-DATE`.

Is there a way to prevent IntelliJ from attaching the debugger? I already tried to set

```
thePluginJavaExecTask.debug = false
```

But it seems to be ignored by IntelliJ (it stills debugs it).

If it makes any difference, I am also the maintainer of the plugin in question. All it does is invoke a Java-based command-line tool. I use `JavaExec` because it is easy to set up (set `main`, `classpath` from a `configuration`, `args`, `inputs` and `outputs`). Perhaps there is a better way?

Comment: Please vote for the related issue: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-200192.

Comment: @CrazyCoder Hmmm, the takeaway from that thread seems to be either mess with the jvmArgs, which breaks up-to-date too, or resort to using Exec. Neither is a good solution, but I guess that's what I have to live with.